# SQL: Select most recent date for each category

Tags: sql

I'm pulling data from a database and one of the tables contain two columns that together identify a location and another column containing a date of each time it was serviced. Is it possible to write a SQL query such that I get the most recent time that each location was serviced?

So if my raw data looks like this:

```
category_a  category_b  date
       1           a     1/1/01
       1           a     2/2/02
       1           b     1/2/01
       1           b     2/3/02
       2           a     1/3/01
       2           a     2/4/02
       2           b     1/4/01
       2           b     2/5/02
```

then the query would return this:

```
category_a  category_b  date
       1           a     2/2/02
       1           b     2/3/02
       2           a     2/4/02
       2           b     2/5/02
```

This would be easy to do if the database was authored in such a way that the category combinations were stored in a separate table. However, I don't control this database, so I can't make changes to it.

Comment: Why is there a (-1) on this question?

Comment: I was wondering the same. I'm no SQL expert, but I thought I explained my question well...

Comment: Maybe you upset someone on another thread, and they retaliated by dinging you here. I've had that happen before.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
SELECT
    category_a,
    category_b,
    MAX(date)
FROM
    Some_Unnamed_Table
GROUP BY
    category_a,
    category_b
ORDER BY
    category_a,
    category_b
```

I certainly don't mind helping people when I can, or I wouldn't be on this site, but did you really search for an answer for this before posting?

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, I didn't have the words to explain this in a google-able fashion. In fact, I ended up reading about CASE statements for 15 minutes before I said "Screw it, someone on SO knows how to answer this." I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Understood. Glad that I could help.

Comment: And 14 years later plus a global pandemic I was also too tired/busy to remember how to do this, googled, and there you go.  Never underestimate the power of SO.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple "group by" using the fact the the "most recent" date is the "highest valued", or `max()`, date

```
select category_a, category_b, max(date)
from mytable
group by category_a, category_b
order by category_a, category_b -- The ORDER BY is optional, but the example data suggests it's needed
```

Answer (score 2):

select category_a,  category_b, max( date) from tbl group by category_a ,category_b;

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select category_a, category_b, max(date) as last_update from table group by category_a, category_b
```