# SQL: Filtering the most recent date entry from a Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am hoping someone can help with this query. The MIN() function isn't working as expected, possibly because I need to have a JOIN in there somewhere but none of the joins I have tried work. Any examples I have found such as [SQL: Select most recent date for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680568/sql-select-most-recent-date-for-each-category) are only basic and don't include multiple rows with matching entries on some columns or are selecting from multiple tables.

```
SELECT TruckNo, MIN(ArrivalDate) AS ArrivalDate, DockId, FreightCode
FROM tblTruckArrival  
WHERE ArrivalDate <> '' AND DockId IN (660,517,86,9,253,685)  
GROUP BY TruckNo, DockId, FreightCode  
ORDER BY TruckNo
```

This returns something like these results which includes multiple ArrivalDates for each DockId when all I want is the next arrival date for each DockId and not future dates. If I remove the FreightCode from the Select statement I get the correct results (presumably because some entries have a different FreightCode for the same DockId) but I need to know what the FreightCode is for each row returned.

```
TruckNo         ArrivalDate     DockId  FreightCode  
22              2018-07-13      253     03WS18  
22              2018-08-29      253     04WS18  
22              2018-10-16      253     05WS18  
22              2018-12-03      253     06WS27  
23              2018-09-02       86     808ES  
23              2018-09-12      685     808ES  
24              2018-11-24       86     810ES  
25              2018-06-17       86     805ES  
25              2018-06-28      517     805ES  
25              2018-12-04      517     810ES  
26              2018-07-03        9     805ES  
27              2018-07-13       86     806ES
```

Should return this:

```
TruckNo         ArrivalDate     DockId  FreightCode  
22              2018-07-13      253     03WS18  
23              2018-09-02       86     808ES  
23              2018-09-12      685     808ES  
24              2018-11-24       86     810ES  
25              2018-06-17       86     805ES  
25              2018-06-28      517     805ES  
26              2018-07-03        9     805ES  
27              2018-07-13       86     806ES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add FreightCode in group by statement, obviously it will give results basis every FreightCode. Correct me if I am wrong, you want the FreightCode corresponding to the each truckno and min arrival date. For that try this out:

```
select a.*,b.freightcode  
from
(select truckno, dockid, min(arrivaldate) as arrivaldate
from tbltruckarrival
where arrivaldate <> '' and dockid in (660,517,86,9,253,685)
group by truckno, dockid) a
left join
tbltruckarrival b
on a.truckno = b.truckno and a.arrivaldate = b.arrivaldate and a.docket_id = b.docket_id
order by a.truckno
```

Let me know in case of any clarifications.

Comment: Why `left join`? Although it can not change result but here just `join` is needed.

Comment: left/inner both can be used, won't really matter much

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @G.Arima Look at execution plan. It could differ on various versions but `inner` usually have less cost.